# How to disable Messaging on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, messaging

Is there a way to stop Windows 10's Messaging from notifying?
How can I Quit it?
I would like to be able to switch it on and off according to my needs: is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After an app showed a notification in the *Action Center* you can disable the app from showing notifications again.

**To prevent a specific app from showing notifications**

- Open the Setting app
- Go to System / Notifications & Actions page
- Scroll down to the *Show notifications from these apps* section
- Turn off the notifications for the specified app or click the app for advanced options

[image: Image showing how to disable notifications from a specified app]

**To prevent all apps from showing notifications**

- Open the Setting app
- Go to System / Notifications & Actions page
- Turn off the *Show app notifications* option

[image: Image showing how to disable all notifications from apps]